# Forcing the CSS animation to end the current loop even after hover is removed

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

I have the following basic CSS animation in a React project. I am trying to trigger the animation on hover, and it works, however once the mouse is off, arrows immediately return to their initial state. Here is the code

CSS :

```
@keyframes arrows-animation {
    from{
        transform: translateX(-5rem);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to{
        transform: translateX(0rem);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}


.arrow-1{
    animation: arrows-animation 1.6s ease-in-out;
}
.arrow-2{
    animation: arrows-animation 1.3s ease-in-out;
}
.arrow-3{
    animation: arrows-animation 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

What I want to achieve is to make the animation to finish the loop or at least get a smoother transition. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit : "arrow-1", "arrow-2" and "arrow-3" are classes applied to svg elements

Comment: How are you applying the classes?